# Take out nearest record of emp.sal which are >50.000

Tags: sql

I want to take out top two record of emp.sal which are >50.000.  Means latest by 50,000.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, your attempts to answer the question, and tag it with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle**:

```
select *
from
(
    select *
    from emp
    where sal > 50000
    order by sal desc
)
where rownum <= 2
```

**MySQL**:

```
select *
from
(
    select *
    from emp
    where sal > 50000
    order by sal desc
)
limit 2
```